# seleniumがインストールできない

Tags: python, anaconda

Anaconda3をインストール。`pip install selenium`でseleniumをインストールしようと試みる、以下のようなエラーが吐き出される。修正方法をご教授いただきたい。

```
 Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000020EB71675F8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] アクセス許可で禁じられた方法でソケットにアクセスしようとしました。',)': /simple/selenium/

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for selenium
```

Comment: Anaconda で pip はトラブルの元と思います。
conda をお勧めします。
http://scienceandtechnology.jp/archives/35881

Answer (score 1):

[WinError 10013]はWindows側でソケットを開かないようにしていることで出るエラーのようです。

調べてみると、以下の原因が考えられるようです。

> 1. ソケットのオープンに管理者権限が必要
> 2. 他のプログラムがすでに同じポートを利用している
> 3. Firewallやアンチウイルスソフトによって制限されている

1の場合、管理者権限の場合は管理者権限を与えることで解決するかもしれません。
3の場合、Firewallやアンチウイルスソフトでの設定が必要になるとおもいます。

[こちらを参考](https://ja.scribd.com/document/359539247/How-to-Fix-WinError-10013)にしました。